# How do I write a function that works like list(zip(...))?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
a = [[1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1]]
b = [[2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]]

def zippy(*args):
  return list(zip(args))

print(zippy(a, b))
>>> [([[1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1]],), ([[2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]],)]

print(list(zip(a, b)))
>>> [([1, 1], [2, 2]), ([0, 0], [3, 3]), ([1, 1], [4, 4])]
```

Someone please explain to me why i'm not getting the exact same output for both. Shouldn't `print(list(zip(a, b)))` return the same result as `print(zippy(a, b))` since the function is returning what was being printed, namely `list(zip(a, b))`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`args` is a tuple containing the passed parameters. You should **unpack** using the 'splat' operator so `zip` works on the items in the tuple (the parameters) and not `args` itself:

```
def zippy(*args):
    return list(zip(*args))
#                   ^
```